# Matplotlib NavigationToolbar embedded in Pyqt5

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt5

I am trying to add a NavigationToolbar to my tool. I managed to embed it in a widget but only the "Save the figure" option (highlighted in green) works. The zoom and the edit options (in red) are disabled. I don't understand why some functionalities don't work while the save option works. Thank you.

My code so far:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Ui_MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.btn_map_country.clicked.connect(self.map_country)
        self.graph2 = MyCanvas()
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.graph2, 0, 2, 1, 1)

    def map_country(self):
        self.graph2.figure.clf()
        self.axes = self.graph2.figure.add_subplot(111)

        map = Basemap(projection='cyl',lon_0=0,resolution='l')
        map.readshapefile('shape_test', 'state')

        countries = ['Australia', 'Canada', 'France', 'Russia']
        patches   = []
        patches2   = []

        for info, shape in zip(map.state_info, map.state):
            if info['ADMIN'] in countries:
                patches.append( Polygon(np.array(shape), True) )
            else:
                patches2.append( Polygon(np.array(shape), True) )

        self.axes.add_collection(PatchCollection(patches, facecolor= '#81F781', edgecolor='k', linewidths=0.5, zorder=2))
        self.axes.add_collection(PatchCollection(patches2, facecolor= '#DAD3D1', edgecolor='k', linewidths=0.5, zorder=2))

        map.drawmapboundary(fill_color='#A9D0F5')
        self.graph2.draw()

class MyCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.figure = plt.figure()
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.figure)
        self.figure.patch.set_facecolor("None")
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
```

Here the result:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not saving a reference to the toolbar, so I'm guessing it is being garbage collected.

Change the toolbar instantiation line to:

```
self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
```

EDIT: Consider following the pattern of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30441868/1994235) stack overflow answer (explicitly add the toolbar and canvas to a Qt layout, etc).